# Phpspreadsheet rounding off the accountnumbers and removing 0 from starting

Tags: laravel-5, phpspreadsheet

I am working on phpspreadsheet where i am downloading the users account details, but phpspreadsheet is rounding off the account numbers and also removing the 0 from starting.

Example:

Original=> 545778985645453699
After PHPSpreadsheet code => 545778985645453700

Original=> 0256884555
After PHPSpreadsheet code => 256884555

I want numbers to be exact like i am pulling from DB using laravel.

Tried, converting datatype but its making cells value to 0. Tried numberformat its also not working.

```
$spreadsheet = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet();
        $sheet = $spreadsheet->getSheet(0);
        $sheet->fromArray($Final, null, 'A1');
        $sheet->getStyle('A1:A1')
            ->getNumberFormat()
            ->setFormatCode(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT);
        $writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx($spreadsheet);
```

Is there any alternate colution for this issue, or am i doing anything wrong here.

Comment: Cast the values as strings in PHP before doing anything with them. They are being treated as numbers, which, technically, they are, so rounding takes place and leading zeros are removed since they aren't significant to the value when it's a number.

Comment: What was the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Quite an old question but I had this problem as well, PHPSpreadSheet was changing big numbers like `1606778294323857` into `1606778294323860`. If you just need to have those values as is and do not need to have it "formatted" (type) as number, this helped me.

Solution was to set the type to String explicitly:

```
$sheet->getCell('A1')->setValue(1606778294323857)->setDataType(DataType::TYPE_STRING);
```

**My version of PHPSpreadSheet: 1.16**